# Alternative of sudo in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm facing a weird problem currently. I've a couple logging units based on Rpi at various places which I normally access via remote SSH to monitor things / update program.

For a particular RPi, I'm not able to run any command with `sudo` which I assume that `sudo` binary has got corrupted somehow since it's giving me `segmentation error`. Now my problem is to run any root level command such as `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or replacing `sudo` binary by `dpkg`. I will be needing `sudo`.

Now my question is : Is there any alternative of `sudo` so that I can get root access and fix this issue ? Please note that I only have remote access to this RPi and hence can't go over there physically to fix this issue or replace this card.

Comment: I think whatver you do you are stuffed.  If sudo is corrupt what else is corrupt?  You have no way of knowing the extent of the SD card corruption so can not really trust any data on that SD card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already given the root user a password you could use the su command.

The su command will prompt you for the root password and if correct will log you in as root.

If you haven't already assigned a password to the root user I know of no solution without physical access to the SD card.

Comment: I haven't touched `root` password. So I guess, I can't use `su`.

Comment: There is no harm in trying, you could try raspberry as the password.  But I doubt that a password has been assigned.  Perhaps also try su and enter a blank password.

Comment: Of course you could copy a good sudo binary to your home directory and try the command ./sudo instead of sudo.

Comment: Last option is worth trying i.e., good binary option, I will let you know. I tried `pi` user's password and blank password while trying `su` but of no use.

Comment: While copying `sudo` binary from another pi and running `./sudo`, it gives me this error `must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`. So I guess, I will have to change it.

Comment: I assume that it must be copied via `root` user and hence I'm getting this error.

Comment: Yes, I was naive to suggest it can be copied.  I didn't realise it was setuid root which means it must be owned by root.  I'm out of ideas.